# Ubuntu / Python : Can't launch Chromium from SubProccess.Popen

Tags: python, ubuntu, chromium, popen

Basicaly, i've plugged an `Arduino` to communicate with my computer and the goal is to open Chromium when i'm clicking a button. When clicked, the arduino will send a string on the `serial communication` and the computer will get this string thanks to a `Python` script.

This script will then launch `Chromium` using `Popen(['chromium-brower'])`

I've been able to do all that without any problem, excepted for the `Chromium` that won't launch. The syntaxe is correct, but the terminal return a weird error that I don't understand.

> sudo python serialtest.py
>       start 
>       [0825/084720:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create /home/dlslabo/.pki/nssdb directory.
>       [0825/084721:FATAL:chrome_main_delegate.cc(386)] Check failed: process_type.empty(). Unable to get the user data directory for
>   process type: zygote
>       #0 0x7f1a233095fe base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
>       #1 0x7f1a23325f8e logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
>       #2 0x7f1a2f3a11f5 
>       #3 0x7f1a2aa8f224 
>       #4 0x7f1a2aa8d80d content::ContentMain()
>       #5 0x7f1a2f3a065a 
>       #6 0x7f1a17a25a40 __libc_start_main
>       #7 0x7f1a2f3a0519

Here is my python program :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial
from subprocess import Popen

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1 :
   line = ser.readline().strip()
   print line
   if line == "start":
      p = Popen(["chromium-browser"])
```

I tried with others app as `Popen(["gedit"])` and `Popen(["firefox"])` and it worked fine. 
From what I read on the internet, this could be because i'm executing the script as super user. But I don't know why this would cause a problem.

Comment: What happens if you do not start it as a super user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a browser (or any other program that isn't for system administration) as the `root` user is a bad idea for security.

It looks like you're using `root` because you need access to a particular device node. In that case, you can make a non-root user the owner of the device. The easiest way to do this is via udev rules. Create a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-tty-acm.rules` with the following content:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM0", OWNER="mynonrootuser", MODE=0660
```

If more users might need access, create a group for them, say `ttyacm`, and set `GROUP="ttyacm"` and `MODE=0660`. [More about writing udev rules here.](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)